# How to change size of date time picker? I'm using ng-pick-date-time

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

How to change size of date time picker? I'm using 'ng-pick-date-time'.
I've inspected calendar and found class '.owl-dt-container'. When change font-size : 1 rem; , calendar is resized. How can I change this property through code or resize calendar on any other way?

Comment: Please provide a minimal stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

Just adapt your components css / scss file.

```
.owl-dt-container {
 font-size : 1 rem;
}
```

Or try to use [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)

```
:host ::ng-deep .owl-dt-container {
    font-size : 1 rem;
}
```

Comment: I found even using the `::ng-deep` notation for the component's style file would not be applied. What worked for me was to put in the global _styles.scss_ where the `@import "~ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css";` exists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in an unconventional method, because I couldn't change the font size in any way from css. I managed to change the font in node-modules / ng-pick-datetime / assets / style / picker.min.css and modified the .owt-dt-container class